# cognos creating full time format

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I keep searching and trying to find way to display time that i subtract between two time stamp as full format like hours:mins:secounds not just hours or mins only

did anyone pass that before

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It kind of depends on how you're performing the calculation.  But you should be able to set the data type to `TIME INTERVAL`, and set your properties as follows:

```
Time Unit --> Time
Time Separator --> :
Display Hours --> Two digits
Display Minutes --> Two digits
Display Seconds --> No
Display Milliseconds --> No
```